# How to print negation output?

Tags: php

```
function count_digit($number) {
   return strlen($number);
 }

  for($a=1; $a<=5000; $a++){ //loop
        $i=$a;
        $i= (string)$i ;

        $num=$a;
        $number_of_digits = count_digit($num);
        if ($number_of_digits == 1){

            $total = $a+$i[0];

        }
        elseif ($number_of_digits == 2){

            $total = $a+$i[0]+$i[1];


        }

         elseif ($number_of_digits == 3){

            $total = $a+$i[0]+$i[1]+$i[2];

        }

         elseif ($number_of_digits == 4){

            $total = $a+$i[0]+$i[1]+$i[2]+$i[3];

        }


        echo $total. '<br>';       
 }
```

output a : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ... 5000

output total : 2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
11
13
15
17
19
21
23
25
27
29
22
24
26
28
30
32
34
36
38
40
33
35
37
39
41
43
45
47
49
51
44
46
48
50

how to make negation output total: 1 3  5  7  9  20  31  42  53

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Comment: Can you describe your requirements in some more details?

Comment: Please, next time add working code example, this one contains error. Simple one, but it's an error.

Comment: @Dagon i want to make output self number https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_number

Comment: @Aleksandar ah sorry. please check again. i already updated the code

Comment: Can you please describe this code a bit. I tried to understand this but without success. I can see some patterns but no clue what they mean. Best thing I achieved without understanding what you are trying to do is to subtract `number_of_digits` from your total formula, like `$total = ($a+$i[0]+$i[1])-2;` or `$total = ($a+$i[0]+$i[1]+$i[2]+$i[3])-4;`. But again, I don't have a clue what you are asking.

Comment: @Aleksandar have you seen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_number ?

First: print 1 - 5000. check if digit 1 then run 1+1, 2+2, 3+3, ... . If digit 2 (10-99) then run 10+1+0, 11+1+1, 25+2+5, ...5000+5+0+0+0

Comment: @Aleksandar i just need code  like `echo !$total. '<br>';`  .
 (Run 1-5000 then negation (output total)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now when I understand what you are asking, lets take this approach.

You have all numbers that are not self numbers, so we will take them to array, as well as all numbers 0-5000 to compare them.

All numbers that are in `all_numbers` array but not in `not_self_numbers` array must be `self numbers`.

```
<?php
$not_self_numbers = array();
$all_numbers = array();

for($a=1; $a<=5000; $a++){ //loop
    $i=$a;
    $i= (string)$i ;
    $all_numbers[] = $a;

    $num=$a;
    $number_of_digits = strlen($num);
    if ($number_of_digits == 1){

        $total = $a+$i[0];
        $not_self_numbers[] = $total;

    }
    elseif ($number_of_digits == 2){

        $total = $a+$i[0]+$i[1];
        $not_self_numbers[] = $total;


    }

        elseif ($number_of_digits == 3){

        $total = $a+$i[0]+$i[1]+$i[2];
        $not_self_numbers[] = $total;

    }

        elseif ($number_of_digits == 4){

        $total = $a+$i[0]+$i[1]+$i[2]+$i[3];
        $not_self_numbers[] = $total;

    }


}
$self_numbers = array_diff($all_numbers, $not_self_numbers);

foreach($self_numbers as $number) {
    echo $number."<br>";
}
```